# file transfer very slow (within the same HD)

Tags: 16.04, files, transfer

I had a previous Ubuntu 16.04 and no problem except Grub was messed up, couldn't solve the problem so I did a clean install. The second install to transfer a file from 1 dir to another (175MB in size) will take over an hr to complete. How can I troubleshoot this problem? 
ps: the hw is the same, the only difference that I remember is I used a newer version of Ubuntu 16.04 the second time.

Comment: Is the disk failing?  Is it a model of drive that has many-many-retries (thus is slow) to prevent warranty repairs, or one quick to report errors? (ie. faster enterprise but with shorter warranty?)  We can't know, have you looked at your SMART data to see if it's not hardware related?  *the slowness makes me think of hardware issues*

Comment: I don't think the disk is failing, until two days ago, with old install, everything was fine, I think it has something to do with configuration, but I don't know a lot about Linux/Ubuntu.

Comment: Checking your disk SMART (`smartctl`, `gnome-disks` etc.) and can explain what you describe, esp. if WD-green or something that retries-many-many-times to avoid warranty thus some parts of disk will be quick, others areas of disk slow as re-reads are constantly required... these issues show up in errors recorded on drive SMART stats if checked (why I suggested it).  You didn't provide a lot of detail; transfer was between the same or similar file-system (ie. no conversion required which may be significant if lots of small/tiny files)...

Comment: Thanks gulverc, since I was at the beginning of install, so I decided to re-install it, now everything is fine, the only difference with previous one is I was mounting a NTFS partition at the start, and in the fstab, I put async instead of sync (previous install I used sync). Is it possible that this might cause the slow down of the disk?